# Find out the kernel of $\phi $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Given $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  given by $\phi(f(x)) := f( \sqrt 2)$ is a ring homomorphism. 
>   Find out the kernel of $\phi $

My  attempt : kernel of $\phi $  is  $x^2-2$

is  its  true  ??

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407657/prove-phi-mathbbzx-rightarrow-mathbbr-given-by-phifx-f-s)

Comment: @jasmine Why are you duplicating questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The kernel of a ring homomorphism is always an ideal.

Comment: That mean @Omnomnomnom .kernel of $\phi $  is  $x^2-2$

Comment: @jasmine but $x^2 - 2$ is not an ideal

Comment: @jasmine note for example that $x(x^2 - 2) = x^3 - 2x$ will also be an element of the kernel.

Comment: thanks u , now got its   @Omnomnomnom .....ur name  is  diificult  to type